# viewing nested classes in propertygrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I'm using classes from a third party that I cant modify and I want to view them in a winforms propertygrid.
The problem is that the grid does not allow me to expand the nested class.  it looks something like this.

[image: propertygrid]

the third party code looks something like this

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("BBB")]
[DataContract]
public class B : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [DataMember]
    private Int32 x;
    [DataMember]
    private Int32 y;
    public Int32 X
    {
        get{return x; }
        set{ x = value;}
    }

    public Int32 Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value;![enter image description here][1]}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs arg)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(sender, arg);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("X {0} , Y {1}", x,y);
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("AAA")]
[DataContract]
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [DataMember]
    private Int32 i = 18;

    [DataMember]
    private Int32 j = 6;

    [DataMember]
    private B b;

    public Int32 I
    {
        get { return i; }
        set { i = value; }
    }

    public Int32 J
    {
        get { return j; }
        set { j = value; }
    }

    public B BB
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("I {0} , J {1} B {2}", i, j, b.ToString());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs arg)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(sender, arg);
    }
}
```

I'm initializing the propertygrid like this

```
A aa = new A();
propertyGrid2.SelectedObject = aa;
```

Answer (score 0):

First when you create the base `A` item you also have to set the value of `BB`, otherwise it is just null.

```
A aa = new A();
aa.BB = new B();
propertyGrid2.SelectedObject = aa;
```

In order to browse the sub items add an `ExpandableObjectConverter` for those items.  In your example for `B` it would look like this:

```
TypeConverterAttribute BAttribute = new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter));
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(B), BAttribute);
```